# Skipping blank cells with an Index/Match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got several databases containing 100/1,000's of rows where the information is presented something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAye9.png]

I need to get all the information relevant to each company onto one row; I'm not able to do a simple Sort & Filter as nearly every company has a different level of detail, so information ends up in the wrong rows. Looks like the best option is an Index/Match formula, but my current formula

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)
```

returns zeros for any result where the first Index/Match result is blank:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP9MO.png]

How can I write the formula so that it skips the blank cells? I'd prefer not to have to use VBA however any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any one column from G to L that will always have data?

Comment: Yes, the first name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively,

Because match is always the return the first value it found.

So in cell G2, 
=INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)+COUNTA($G$1:G$1)-1)

Or by matching the header to offset the cells.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I can make this work on the mock database I provided, but not on any of the full size ones.  What do you mean by matching the header to offset the cells?

Comment: Assuming the number of row for each companies is fixed and the pattern are the same. You can use the column number to offset to the second/third/fourth row, meaning column 1 will be on the first row, column 2 will be on the second row. So, It will look like this, =INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)+MATCH(Sheet2!G$1,Sheet1!$G$1:$L$1,0)-1)

Comment: That's part of the problem - the number of rows per company is not fixed.  Maybe I need to come up with a formula to insert rows so they all have the same number - is this possible?

Comment: This might look a bit complicated but it might work. Create a new column in sheet1 with the formula Cell M1 =MATCH("*",G2:L2,0)&A2, then in sheet2 use the formula below, so what it does u make each row unique by combining the column number & the company. Then, just basically lookup for the unique text. Hope it make sense.
 =INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(MATCH(Sheet2!G$1,Sheet1!$G$1:$L$1,0)&$L3,Sheet1!$L:$L,0))

Comment: Thanks Kevin, managed to get the Sheet1 Match formula to work, but not the second longer one for Sheet2 - I'm getting a #N/A response.  All I've done is add the formulas to Sheet1 and Sheet2; is there a step I've missed?

Comment: I am sorry i made a mistake, this should be the correct one. i just tested this. =INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(MATCH(Sheet2!G$1,Sheet1!$G$4:$L$4,0)&$A2,Sheet1!$M:$M,0))

Comment: To confirm, that formula should be pasted in Sheet2 Cell G2?  Because I'm still getting a #N/A response?

Comment: Sheet1!$M:$M is meant for the new column u created with the formula =MATCH("*",G2:L2,0)&A2, where do you put your new column?

Comment: O sorry again, This should work. i reference to the wrong header in Sheet1. =INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(MATCH(Sheet2!G$1,Sheet1!$G$1:$L$1,0)&$A2,Sheet1!$M:$M,0))

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your existing formula in an `IF` function:

```
=IF(Sheet2!$A2<>"",INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),"")
```

Comment: This only works to column G - from column H onward, where there's one or more blanks at the top of each row in that companies group it returns a zero.

Answer (score 0):

I will normally use a "Go To Special" function for this.

Say for example for the sample data below.

[image]

I will put in the first formula '=IF(B2<>"",C3,"")'. Copy that cell (Ctrl+C), then select cells from C2 to C7 and use the 'Go to special' to select Blank cells only under Home tab, in Editing > Find & Select > Go To Special. Simply just Paste the formula to all the blank cells by Ctrl+V. You will get all the information in one row on the first row for each companies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So that will land the value `B` into cell C5, where it does not belong. Rethink that approach.

Comment: No it doesn't the formula is actually referring to the cell below. So it will return 'E' in C5

Comment: Right, but it fails when a value is missing, e.g. no phone number. The OP said the level of details varies.

Comment: In that case, you may try the formula below on your sheet2, Cells G2 =INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)+COUNTA($G$1:G$1)-1)

Comment: because match is always found the first match, so need to find ways to offset from the cells it found.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

Create a pivot table with your data and in the pivot options select 0 for the blank cells.Copy all the fields into row area...

Step2:

Apply conditional formatting as shown in the below image to remove (blank) cells.

[image]

Note: This is not a robust solution but worked for me.

Comment: I get a row for every blank cell saying "(blank)" even after going to PivotTable Analyze>PivotTable>Options>Layout & Format>Format>For empty cells show: 0.  Or have I misunderstood your instructions?

Comment: Edited my answer..Please check!